# Making External API calls from nodejs that has OAuth2.0 set up

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, oauth-2.0, integration

So I want to get data from Dynamics 365 CRM store it on my MongoDB through a NodeJs server, process it, and send it to a completely different system.

Dynamics 365 CRM has OAuth2.0 to give access to the endpoint and I can't figure out how do I make calls to external API in NodeJs that has OAuth2.0 set up. Can someone please give me a hint to where I should look?

Thanks in advance!